# absolutely positioned div is below another div

Tags: css

When I click an image from the table, a popup appears. But when I click on one of images in the last row, it is cut off by the div below it.

I can't post relevant css as there is too much but I can post the page.

[link](http://thibaut.joladev.com/catalog/collections/details/collection/expeditions)

Click on the last image below "wallpaper - click thumbnail to view details" (before printed fabrics section starts).

Actually, same thing happens if you click on the last image under "printed fabrics" as well.

How can I make it appear on top ?

Comment: Provide a fiddle, will be easier to help

Comment: I can't reproduce the whole thing on fiddle

Comment: one recommendation for you .. you've created separate detail container for all `td`s but its not recommended, just create a single div and move it to the cursor's position and then display it ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's `overflow: hidden` on the container that is causing the problem. What you can do is to change this (global.css 1423):

```
.wallpaper_collection {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

to something like this:

```
.wallpaper_collection:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

You will have to do the same for the other container(s). E.g. (line 1428)

```
.printed_fabrics_collection {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

You could just combine them into one rule, like so:

```
.wallpaper_collection:after, .printed_fabrics_collection:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

Comment: I am trying to do that in firebug but then they dont stay in the same positions, and also content:"" rule disappears after I write it.

Comment: Hey Ralph, just setting display: table instead of overflow does it! Thanks so much!

Comment: Glad it helped, though I can't guarantee just `display: table` on its own will work everywhere. The code I posted above is called the "clearfix" method (which has various incarnations now) and is an alternative to using `overflow: hidden`. Anyhow, if you find any bugs, keep that code handy. :-)